# Is there a more Pythonic way to write this? Filling multiple lists to desired length

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm struggling with making my lists of strings a DataFrame because they are different sizes.

So, I'm running code to get the length of the largest list and then adding 'Null' to the other lists until they are all the same size.

Problem is I have 7 lists and need to repeat the below code for all of them and it feels terribly redundant/repetitive. Any ideas to revise?

```
# Using entry 4 for the purpose of this example (this repeats for each lenX value)
# Getting lengths and max length
len4 = len(list4)
lenMax = max(len1, len2, len3, len4, len5, len6, len7)

# defining function to allow adding str to list as multiple elements
def createlist4 (size4, value4):
    requiredlist4 = [value]*size
    return requiredlist4

size4 = (lenMax - len4)
value4 = 'Null'
diff4 = createlist4(size4, value4)
newlist4 = list4 + diff4
```

> Output newlist4 = List filled to desired length (lenMax) with original values + 'Null' as repeating value.

Any ideas or advice here?

---

Please see response of @Freddy Mcloughlan for answer.

Comment: You may want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "I have 7 lists and need to repeat the below code for all of them and it feels terribly redundant/repetitive" ... sounds like you want to put that code in a function and call it for each list

Comment: How are you creating `list1` and `list2` ... `list7` ?

Comment: @Freddy Mcloughlan - The lists are created from extracting all strings from a spreadsheet before separating the values into lists based on conditions. 

For clarity, list4 = some list of strings.

Following that the goal is to create a DataFrame from my lists and put into a newly categorised spreadsheet.

Comment: I suggest you create a master list called `lists`, and append each new bit of data to it, rather than hard coding each list like `list1 = ...`. Then my answer will be much easier

Comment: Difficulty is that it is strings only and it is necessary that they remain separated, as each list is another column in my DataFrame. Point is to extend each list to the same size so they will match up to be DataFramed.

Comment: As you are asking for being more pythonic, note that in Python `camelCase` is not the naming convention for variables nor methods. You should use `snake_case`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `extend` to add on `None` values for the lists:

Example values:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [1, 2]
list3 = [1, 2, 3]
```

```
# Add all your lists into one large list
lists = [list1, list2, list3]

# This gets the longest length in lists
lenMax = max(len(x) for x in lists)
# This is the value you are extending by
value = None  # Not 'null' (I'm assuming None is more suitable)

for i in range(len(lists)):
    # For every list, extend it with values (len-max - len) times
    lists[i].extend([value] * (lenMax - len(lists[i])))
```

```
>>> lists
[[1, 2, None],
 [1, 2, None],
 [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment, this would be the ideal way to do it however have tried this already. Met with error "'str' object has no attribute 'extend'" - As it is a list of strings, no ints.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Are you sure `lists` is 2 dimensional? (lists in lists `[[],[],[]]`)?

Comment: My god Freddy you are so smart. And I'm so dumb. Thank you so much.

This is the correct answer, resolved.

Comment: @User41824474 No worries man 